# Is $\hat S$ a function?

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis

Let $S(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty (-1)^n\chi_{(n,n+1)}(x)$. Find the Fourier transformation of $S(x)$. Is $\hat{S}$ a function?

$$\hat{S}=\int_R \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty (-1)^n\chi_{(n,n+1)}(x) dx=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n i e^{-iny}(e^{-iy}-1)}{y} $$

How do I show that the fourier transformation is or isn't a function?

Comment: Does the definition of your "function" include generalized function, or distribution?

Comment: I believe it is distribution.

Comment: @UsernameUnkown: Why am I only getting 35 points for the answer instead of the 50 points of the bounty? :-)

Comment: I need to wait 24 hours to award the bounty completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a function in the usual sense but generalized function or distribution.

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty (-1)^ne^{-iny}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{in(-y+(2m+1)\pi)}=\delta(-y+(2m+1)\pi),\ \forall m\in{\mathbf Z},$$
for different branch cuts. So
$$\hat S = \frac{i}{y}(e^{-iy}-1)\delta(-y+(2m+1)\pi),\ \forall m\in{\mathbf Z}$$
for different branch cuts, a Dirac delta function distribution, or generalized function.